# Telegram: Create desktop shortcut

Tags: telegram

Solved :)
Use the Web-based application. Each group/channel has a link corresponding to it; make an internet shortcut for it. Methods vary for different OSs.

I use Telegram often and want to create a shortcut to my desktop of some specific groups and channels.

Is there a way to do this. It just doesn't seem there is any visible option on the Desktop app.

Comment: You may create a short cut that opens a web address, put the group url there. Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: Yes, I was actually trying for the desktop app though, since browsers are normally resource intensive, but seems web option works too. Thanks @SeverusSnape

Comment: Consider posting an answer, Aniruddh. And mark your answer as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows 10:

Rather than using the desktop version; use the web version.
Create an online shortcut using the steps:

1. Go to the specific website/channel you wish to create a shortcut of
2. Click on the lock element in the url bar
3. Drop it into your desktop/any other folder
4. Rename the shortcut to your convenience.

The Desktop version does not provide shortcut facilities.